# Probability distribution to simulate number of users

Tags: probability, distributions

I need to simulate with probability distribution number of users who are listening radio during the day. Given data : max number of users is 1000, day has 24 hours (from 0 to 24), the highest number of users should be from 11 to 15. Which probability distribution will be the best and which parameters of distribution should I use?

Comment: Try to imagine the data-generating process. When do people usually listen to the radio? The shortest answer is it depends - different groups have different patterns, different waking and sleeping hours; thus you will most likely have a mixture of distributions. I don't quite get your constraint on the maximum number of users.

Comment: Is the max number of users an imposed maximum or the maximum observed?

Answer (score 1):

You may use a [Birth-Death](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birth%E2%80%93death_process) process: a "birth" is a new user tuning in, a "death" is a listener tuning out. If you adjust the rates of the process properly, you will not need to introduce the maximum users cut-off explicitly.

Comment: This is a good idea only if his observation data has high granularity (ie- minutes). If he only has data by hours (which the question seems to imply), I'm not so sure a continuous Markov Chain would be appropriate. In the specific case of a Birth-Death process, it wouldn't work because I'm sure the differences between hours is more than 1. I'm not too refreshed on Markov Chains, however, so feel free to correct me :)